# How to account one record in kibana in several aggregation items

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

We're running reports over our application(s) log files, which are collected in an elastic search storage. The logs have among others following fields

```
@timestamp:
    Oct 24, 2023 @ 20:15:52.043
Action:
    INSTALL
Components:
    a; b
UserName:
    U12345
```

Ultimately, I'd need to run a query which will group by components, and return count of installs and unique users who've made these.

I'm able to group by in a query by the raw Components field, getting as result something like

```
{
   "key" : "a;b",
   "doc_count" : 10,
   "unique_user_ids" : {
        "value" : 2
   }
},
{
   "key" : "a;c",
   "doc_count" : 8,
   "unique_user_ids" : {
        "value" : 1
   }
},
```

However I can't figure out how to count each record as many times as a component is listed, getting as result something like

```
{
   "key" : "a",
   "doc_count" : 18,
   "unique_user_ids" : {
        "value" : 3
   }
},
{
   "key" : "b",
   "doc_count" : 10,
   "unique_user_ids" : {
        "value" : 2
   }
},
{
   "key" : "c",
   "doc_count" : 8,
   "unique_user_ids" : {
        "value" : 1
   }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the data that you are getting in, the best way to do it would be to split the key prior to indexing it. In other words your records should become:

```
{
   "key" : ["a", "b"],
   "user_name" : "foo"
},
{
   "key" : ["a", "c"],
   "user_name" : "bar"
},
```

A much slower solution that doesn't require reindexing your data would be to use a runtime field to split components. The runtime field can be defined either in the query or [in the index mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html). Here is an example of how to do it on the query:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "key": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "user_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_doc/1
{
   "key" : "a;b",
   "user_name" : "foo"
}

PUT test/_doc/2?refresh
{
   "key" : "a;c",
   "user_name" : "bar"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "keys": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": """
        def combined_key = /;/.split(doc['key'].value);
        for (key in combined_key) {
          emit(key)
        }
      """
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keys"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, query suggestion works perfectly! I also have full control on the data,  it's just a bit complicated (we wanted to revise all the use cases before applying any changes), but we'll move from runtime scripts to a adjusted data model eventually

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you! There are many optimization that take place when you run terms aggregations on a keyword field. All these optimizations are no longer applicable the moment you start messing with the values using the script as in my second examples. So, a query can slow down dramatically, I saw 10x slow down in some case. That's why I provided it as a less desirable slower solution. However, if a query used to take 10ms and now it takes 100ms I can see how you might choose to live with it for while (comparing to say a jump from 2s to 20s. :) )